# ModelForm is not displaying entry fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I am struggling with displaying fields in my view in Django.
The submit button appears but the fields related to models do
not.
Here is my code:

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from blog.models import Comments

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
```

Models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    entries_id = models.ForeignKey(Entries)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField("date published")
```

Views.py

```
class CommentListView(ListView):

    model = Comments

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
    def add_comment(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = CommentForm()

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST.copy())
            if form.is_valid():
                context = dict(form = form)
            return render_to_response('comments_list.html', context) # etc.
```

The template:

```
{% extends 'flatpages/default.html' %}


    {% block body %}

    {% for Comments in object_list reversed %}
    <p>{{ Comments.text }} </p></br>
    <p>{{ Comments.author }}</p>

{% empty %}
    <p>No comments yet</li></p>
{% endfor %}

<div="form" >    
<form method = 'post' action =''> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
 </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: How is the form supposed to be getting into the context?

Comment: The fact that I don't understand the question tells me that you may be on the right track. Could you elaborate on that?:)

Comment: I have solved the question. I was using the wrong view in urls it's now working. Thank you for your hint I now do know what is context.

Answer (score 0):

You are not always giving a value to *form*. At least, I would do that:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CommentListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['now'] = timezone.now()
    context['form'] = CommentForm()
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but after adding the "form" value, the form is still not visible in the template view.

Comment: I have successful transactions and I have also tried to remove the css also with the same effect.

[12/May/2014 19:00:58] "GET /comments/css.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1299
[12/May/2014 19:01:57] "GET /comments/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1299

Comment: 200 is not an error. Your message only means that the css file was successfully loaded.

Comment: Only the token is generated as viewing in inspect element. Chrome plugin isn't showing any errors